# onLoad happening multiple times with Iframe

Tags: angular

Having some issues with Angular 2, im making a component that has a iframe and sets the source from the input. However when it loads, it hits onLoad twice, one with `src=''` and another with the actual input url.

I cant seem to figure out how to hook the url up for the iframe when it gets put into the view.

```
export class ExternalComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    url: string;

    private src: any;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    }

    ngOnInit()    
    {
        this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url)
    }

    onLoad() {

    }
}
```

Html:

```
<iframe [src]="src" frameBorder="0" (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>
```

Reproduction: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnpmv6X2IO3WGQAg0372?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: Where's the iframe?

Comment: It was hidden by the class code, it is there now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try an attribute binding, which isn't added at all if the value is `null`

```
<iframe [attr.src]="src ? src = null" frameBorder="0" (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>
```

**update**

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880489/217408
when the event handler is added to the element before the `<iframe>` is added to the DOM. This seems to be what Angular is doing.

Add event handler imperatively after the element was added to the DOM

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6PmFmlwAkhOYfU4Hgv20?p=preview)

Ignore events while `url` is null

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tjVN9YGWYN68UkmeKIF5?p=preview)

Comment: Still happening even with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Nice, I have a question though, as trying the other thin answer doesn't generate double events. Is this normal or are we just making a solution to a error that should not exist?

Comment: As in, is the error somewhere else in the code, that should be fixed so event only comes once

Comment: To me it sounds like some weird Chrome behavior that should be fixed there.

Answer (score 5):

Using debugger I found out that `event.target.src` could provide the solution. The first time it runs, it is an empty string `""`. The second time the value is the image url. So, in my case it works like that:

```
onLoad(event: any) {
  if (event.target.src) {
      //do some stuff here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit()    
    {
        this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url)
    } 
This is wrong code if use like this iframe will load more time .
ts file 
ngOnInit()    
    {
        this.src = this.url;
    } 
make html page like this (use pipe)
<iframe [src]="src| safe" ></iframe>

pipe file

      import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
      return   this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

'onLoad executed' runs only once in this example (http://plnkr.co/edit/wRZTH8?p=preview). Are you sure something else is not going on?

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<iframe [attr.src]="url ? url : null" frameBorder="0" (load)="onLoad()" style="width:200px;height:200px"></iframe>`
})
export class AppComponent implements ngOnInit{
    public url: any;

    constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){

    }

    ngOnInit()    
    {
        this.url =     this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://www.nekkon.com');
    }

    onLoad() {
        console.log('onLoad executed');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my more advanced example that does it.  http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnpmv6X2IO3WGQAg0372?p=preview